# How to account for an unknown return type for a Java Function

Tags: java, mysql

I have a function that returns the result of a query. The input arguments are the SQL statement and the field to be retrieved, while the output is the result of the query. As expected, the database contains multiple data types. Is there a generic return type I can specify the function to have?

The code below retrieves string...I need to change this to return Integer types as well, preferably, without writing another function.

```
public static String dbConnect(String sql,String field) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Statement stmt;
    String DB_URL;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://connectionURL.net:3306/db?autoReconnect=true"; 
    Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER, DB_PWD);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    String result=null;
    while(rs.next()){
            result  = rs.getString(field);
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The might be a better way to do this, but you can always have your function return an `Object` - which will then have to be cast into whatever you actually expect to get.

But if you do that, perhaps having multiple methods for the various data types you expect might be easier.

(As an aside, reconnecting to the database for every query you run seems like a bad idea.)

Answer (score 5):

Probably, the best way to do it is having two different methods which call a same "base" method.

```
public static ObjectThatCanGetItemAsAnything getItemGenerator(){
    return objectThatCanGetItemAsAnything;
} 

public static String getItemAsString(){
    return getItemGenerator().getStringValue();
}

public static String getItemAsInteger(){
    return getItemGenerator().getIntegerValue();
}

String lol = MyClass.getItemAsString();
Integer test = MyClass.getItemAsInteger();
```

---

Another way would be to have generics methods, this way you can call `getItem()` and it will return the Type you want.

```
public static <T> T getItem(){
    return (T) myObject;
}

String lol = MyClass.<String>getItem();
Integer test = MyClass.<Integer>getItem();
```

---

You can also return `Object` (the method above will act like this if you don't set the generics) and cast it later in your application.

```
public static Object getItem(){
    return myObject;
}

String lol = (String) MyClass.getItem();
Integer test = (Integer) MyClass.getItem();
```

Comment: 5 years late for this, but just started learning java  a few months ago. In your last example. Would this be a case for `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` for the local variable being casted? this has been something i have struggled with coming from only using dynamic languages.

Answer (score 2):

errr, you have a connect function that isn't connecting, it's connecting, then executing.  Better to pull all the execution code out of that function and just have it do connection:

```
public static Connection dbConnect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    String DB_URL;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://connectionURL.net:3306/db?autoReconnect=true"; 
    Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER, DB_PWD);
    return conn;

}
```

then make a new function to execute:

```
public String execute(String sql,String field, Connection conn)
{
    Statement stmt;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    String result=null;
    while(rs.next()){
            result  = rs.getString(field);
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    return result;
}
```

then make your calling code convert the string to int if needed

```
Connection conn = MyClass.dbConnect();
result = mything.execute(someSql, field, conn);
Integer i = Integer.pareseInt(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One Crude solution would be to return an Object instead of String or Integer.Later you can type cast it to either String or Integer(Have if statements and use instanceOf())